# Combine except and else in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, exception, try-catch

Consider you have two functions `func1` and `func2`, where `func2` is the fallback option for `func1`. However, you can also choose by a flag to always go for `func2`. Is there a way to avoid redundant code and unite except/else since they have the same content?

```
if func1_flag == true:
    try:
        func1()
    except:
        func2()
else:
    func2()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `assert` that `func1_flag` is `True` in a `try` block before calling `func1`, and call `func2` in the exception handler:

```
try:
    assert func1_flag
    func1()
except:
    func2()
```

Note that you should specify the exact exception types in the `except` statement if you know which ones `func1` produces.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but it's kind of ugly.

```py
try:
    if not func1_flag:
        raise Exception
    func1()
except:
    func2()
```

This will raise an exception if the func1_flag is false. Then the except block is executed.
You could raise an exception in `func1()` either.

But I don't see a big problem in your style.